# pandas if statements iterating through rows

Tags: pandas

I am trying to create an if/then statement that goes through each row I have in a pandas table, but i'm not able to figure out how to do it.

```
entry_price = df['0VWAP']
low_price = df['0L']
df["stopped"] = low_price < .95*entry_price
for row in df:
    if df['stopped'].bool == True:
        print 'Stopped out'
    else:
        print 'Open'
```

When I run this code, it prints Open for everything when it should be a mix of the two.

Comment: You're iterating over `row`, but aren't checking it at all in your `if` statement. Try something like `if row.stopped:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to print `'Stopped out'` and `'Open'` in your `if` statement, then you can just simply do this:

```
for row in df["stopped"]:
    if row > 0:
        print ('Stopped out')
    else:
        print ('Open')
```